# UIScreen scale factor is 1.0 in iPhone Simulator 4.0.2?

Tags: objective-c, ios-simulator, iphone-4

Am I missing something about the @2x graphics on the iPhone 4?

I'm running the 4.0.2 SDK in the iPhone Simulator, but UIScreen has a scale of 1.0, isn't it supposed to be 2.0 and load high res images automatically?

here's what's I'm testing:

```
 NSLog(@"system version: %@", [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion]);
 NSLog(@"scale factor: %.1f ", [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]);
```

and it prints:

> system version: 4.0.2
>
> scale factor: 1.0

Is it a problem in the Simulator? Or I miss some magical key that I need to enable to make the UIScreen allow 2x graphics?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using the iPhone 4 simulator?

Hardware -> Device -> iPhone 4.

The scale depends on the device, not the OS version.

Comment: 10x Jerry, I somehow missed this option ... Interesting XCode starts by default the iPhone 3 Simulator, even though my version of XCode does not support ANY iPhone 3.x.x SDK ... gosh ..

Comment: Remember, it's DEVICE we are talking about here. You can still run the 4.0 OS on an old generation iPhone.

Comment: Aye: Hardware version != software version.